# HTML Textarea cannot recognize new line

Tags: dojo, newline

I am grabbing data from SQL and displaying it on a `SimpleTextArea` as shown below:

`<textarea data-dojo-type="dijit/form/SimpleTextarea" data-dojo-props="value:at('rel:', 'xml')" data-dojo-attach-event="onBlur: dataChanged" style="resize:none"></textarea>`

The data is an XML document and hence has a lot of new lines:

```
<title> 
<body> 
</body> 
</title>
```

However, in my `SimpleTextArea` everything is showing up in a single line:

```
<title> <body> </body> </title>
```

How can I identify new lines coming from SQL? The data type for this field is `ntext`.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your code? normally you can feed textareas the newline character \n. try to set the value of the texarea to somehting like this:

```
<title>\n<body>\n</body>\n</title>
```